# Splitting one activity into several XML files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

So the problem is, I now use Android studio to write a quite simple app, which has just one activity, but several views, which appear and get gone depending on what the user wants. It all looks smooth and fine, just the problem is all the views are written inside the same main activity layout XML file, which really becomes huge and difficult to navigate and keep track of. What I want to ask, if there are any means to curtail such a problem, like, say, split one huge activity XML file into several shorter ones and then "combine" them?

Comment: You can create multiple xml files then just use the ```include``` tag in your main layout

Comment: Got it! Thank yoU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create several xml files and include in xml file.

activity layout file:

```
<include
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/yourlayout" />
```

sub layout file: name as yourlayout.xml

```
   <YourView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You can refer following URL.

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html